# More than one 2d array inside class

Tags: c++, arrays, class

I have following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Table
{
     float time_table[800][600];
//   float player_table[800][600];

public:

Table(){}

void out(){
    for(int i;i<800;++i){
        for(int j;j<600;++j){
            time_table[i][j]=0.0;
    //      player_table[i][j]=0.0;
        }
    }
}

void change(float x, float y, float time, float player){
       time_table[int(x)][int(y)]=time;
//     player_table[int(x)][int(y)]=player;
}

void showtime(int i, int j){
    cout<<time_table[i][j];
}

//  void showplayer(int i, int j){
//      cout<<player_table[i][j];
//  }

};

int main(){

Table tab;
return 0;

}
```

and it seems to work. However, when I uncomment all the lines above it crashes. Can somenone explain me why? (I'm using Codeblocks 13.12 with GCC 4.8.1 on Windows) Thanks in advance.

Comment: Crashes? How? Do you get any error messages? If so, what?

Comment: The way you've done things, this is allocating all the space on the stack--you're almost certainly just running out of stack space. Obvious solution would be to create your 2D arrays as a vector + a thin layer to do the 2D addressing.

Comment: Thanks guys for quick response! Sorry for duplicating - I haven't found this thread. Btw, is it possible to find out how big is stack (or maybe it's "hardware-software-dependent" issue)?